# Afraid to buy new ceiling fans -- what if the remote is lost or broken?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I don't know how we can buy these new ceiling fans if they all use remotes. I'm afraid of losing the remote, or it breaks. Then what? Replace the whole fan if the manufacturer doesn't make that model any more? What do you do if your ceiling fan remote breaks?

Comment: I imagine they are just harder to find, like dumb TVs.  Just did a fast search and did get a couple of hits with no remote fans, the rest of the hits were for remote fans and how-tos when remote is broken/loss.  Do not know why everyone wants to just sit around pushing buttons, when exercise you can get by getting up and walking to a switch.

Comment: @crip659 It's not an issue of lazy. It's an issue of [Energy Star requiring](https://www.energystar.gov/sites/default/files/specs//private/Ceiling_Fan_V2.3_Program_Requirements_0.pdf) that speed control pull chains, if used, be no more than 80 inches from the floor, and contractors not wanting to do additional control wiring needed for light, fan, and speed.

Comment: You can get "smart" fans that connect to your network for operation from your phone or your home automation system... or retrofit fans with controllers that interface this way.

Answer (score 2):

### Just don't get a DC fan

Classical ceiling fans can be installed with a wall control system, even though they come with a remote + receiver, as the fan motor and light themselves will accept 120VAC without issue.  Unfortunately, newfangled "DC" ceiling fans rely on the receiver to generate the appropriate waveforms for their fan motor, so you can't use them with a wall control system.

Answer (score 1):

Our last one came with a remote holder, that is screwed to the wall. The remote lives in it permanently.

If you are worried about it, ask for another remote as a condition of purchase.